# Is it possible to have a buffer overflow in recv() in C?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, recv

I wonder about a buffer overflow in my app.
For example I have this code:

```
    enum { BUFSIZE = 1024};
    char username[this->BUFSIZE];
    memset(username,0,BUFSIZE);
    char password[this->BUFSIZE];
    memset(password,0,BUFSIZE);

    send(client_fd, "Login: ", BUFSIZE, 0);
    recv(client_fd,username,sizeof(username),0)
```

Can a malicious attacker type more than 1024 chars and do a bof?

Comment: Don't forget that C strings need space for the termination symbol `'\0'`. Currently a UDP operation could fill your username entirely, rendering a invalid C string, which could crash your program later. Check the return value of recv to catch this and add a `\0` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

send(client_fd, "Login: ", BUFSIZE, 0);

-- For this statement, send will try to send BUFSIZE bytes though your string is only "Login: ". send doesn't inherently try to understand a 'C' string. It just recognizes a byte stream. So, your statement for send is incorrect.

recv(client_fd,username,sizeof(username),0)

-- In case of recv, though you have mentioned "sizeof(username)", it doesn't mean it will return "sizeof(username)" bytes, the number of bytes returned can be found out using the return value of recv. Never try to interpret the contents of the buffer passed to recv without checking the return value of recv. But, specifying sizeof(username) ensures that recv call will not return more than sizeof(username) bytes back even if more number of bytes are present in the network buffer.